# Get the URI the MPNS to returns to the push client when creating a notification channel Windows Phone 7

Tags: client-server, push-notification, windows-phone-7.1, mpns

```
/*Get the URI that the Microsoft Push Notification Service returns to the Push Client when creating a notification channel.
Normally, a web service would listen for URIs coming from the web client and maintain a list of URIs to send                
notifications out to. */

string subscriptionUri = TextBoxUri.Text.ToString();
```

Further information on how the pushclient would then sync the URI with a webservice lacks in the description given on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202970%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).
So, does anyone know how to make my app send its URI to the MPNS using the push notification client of the Windows Phone, iso having to manually copy-paste them into my web application? 
Greetz GP

Answer (score 1):

See MSDN Windows Phone Code Samples at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744(v=vs.92).aspx

The following code snippet from the 'sdkToastNotificationCS' example show a possible location to store the uri or send to your webservice:

```
void PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated(object sender, NotificationChannelUriEventArgs e)
    {

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            // Display the new URI for testing purposes.   Normally, the URI would be passed back to your web service at this point.
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.ChannelUri.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Channel Uri is {0}",
                e.ChannelUri.ToString()));
            // Instead of showing the URI in a message box, POST to your web service

        });
    }
```

Execute an HTTP POST request to send the URI and an identifier for you push user. Receive this POST data on your web service and store the user/URI so you can push notifications to that user from your web service.

Answer (score 0):

You just need an endpoint on your server that the app can send the PNS uri (and any other relevant information) to.